# Tsql recursive joins

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(       
        URL VARCHAR(200),
        URLREDIRECT VARCHAR(200),
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL1','URL2'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL2','URL3'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL3','URL4'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL5','URL6'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL6','URL7'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT     'URL7','URL8'
```

The above data defines if a URL is redirected or not, I want to be able to figure out how many times a URL is redirected, so URL 1 would be redirected 3 times since URL1 is redirected first to URL2 which in turn redirects to URL3 which in turn redirects to URL4.

Comment: How does url5 point to two different redirect URLS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more than you were looking for, but here's a recursive CTE implementation that includes a check to see if the URLs are looping back around, and bails out if trapped in a loop...

```
create table urls (       
    url VARCHAR(200),
    urlRedirect VARCHAR(200)
)

insert into urls select 'URL1','URL2'
insert into urls select 'URL2','URL3'
insert into urls select 'URL3','URL4'
insert into urls select 'URL5','URL6'
insert into urls select 'URL5','URL7'
insert into urls select 'URL6','URL8'
insert into urls select 'URL9','URL10'
insert into urls select 'URL10','URL11'
insert into urls select 'URL11','URL12'
insert into urls select 'URL12','URL9'

; with recursiveCTE as (
select 
    url as topURL, 
    url, 
    urlRedirect, 
    cast(url + '->' + urlRedirect as varchar(max)) as tree, 
    1 as depth,
    0 as infiniteLoop
from urls

union all

select 
    r.topUrl, 
    t.url, 
    t.urlRedirect, 
    cast(r.Tree + '->' + t.urlRedirect as varchar(max)), 
    r.depth + 1,
    case 
        when r.tree like '%' + t.url + '->' + t.urlRedirect + '%'
        then 1
        else 0
    end as infiniteLoop
from 
    recursiveCTE r 
    join urls t 
        on t.URL = r.urlRedirect
        and r.infiniteLoop = 0
),
deepest as (
select 
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by topUrl order by depth desc) as rn
from recursiveCTE
)
select
    topURL,
    tree,
    depth,
    infiniteLoop
from deepest
where rn = 1
order by topURL
```

### [SQL Fiddle Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/104b5/1)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/475f5/5/0)

From here I think you can get it.  Note: I altered some of your data due to oddities like URL5 being pointed to URL6 and 7... not sure how one address can have two destinations.

```
with cte as 
(Select url, urlredirect, 1 as lvl 
 from mtable where url='URL1'
 UNION ALL
 Select a.url, a.urlredirect, b.lvl+1
 from mtable a
 inner join cte b on a.url=b.urlredirect
 where a.url<>'URL1')

 Select * from cte
```

so to find the max redirects get get max from `lvl` in the `Select * from cte`